# Support C++11 syntax in c++-mode

Tags: c++, cc-mode

I want correct indentation with my C++ code.

The following piece of code indents properly. It nicely indents the access label and the member declaration independently.

```
class Test : public Base {
 public:
  int a;
};
```

However if I add a final keyword, the `public` won't indent half-ways anymore.

```
class Test final : public Base {
public:
  int a;
};
```

If I go check with `C-c C-s`, in the first case the line with `public` returns `((inclass 1011) (access-label 1011))`. But for the second case it returns `((label 1011))`. Looks like `c++-mode` is not able to detect that the second case is also a class definition, not a function definition.

I wonder if I have to do something to `c++-mode` for it to support C++11 syntax.

Comment: `M-x` `report-emacs-bug`?

Comment: @PythonNut Well, haha I never knew there is a function like that. Since C++11 is around for soooo long, my guess is that this feature is implemented somewhere else I don't know.

Comment: C++11 is so large and complex that tools like Emacs are slowly, incrementally adding support. You definitely might want to look into filing a bug. I doubt there's a magic `enable C++11` switch.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this has been fixed in Emacs 25.1.